# ERROR 1111: 1111: Invalid use of group function SQL Statement:

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, trigger

Uso mysql Workbench y no me deja insertar nada en la tabla de productos compra.
¿Que solución puedo implementar? He intentado usar el HAVING en vez del WHERE pero nada. Me sale el ERROR: 1111 cuando hago el insert into en la tabla.

El error:
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
INSERT INTO `access1`.`productoscompra` (`cantidad`, `compras_idCompras`, `productos_Codigo`) VALUES ('3', '12', '1119');

ERROR 1111: 1111: Invalid use of group function
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `access1`.`productoscompra` (`cantidad`, `compras_idCompras`, `productos_Codigo`) VALUES ('3', '12', '1119')

(los productos esos ya lo he probado sin el trigger y si me deja insertarlos)

```
/*No me deja insertar nada en la tabla productoscompra, a pesar de que el disparador se me crea bien*/
        /*USO MySQL Workbench*/
        delimiter $ 
        CREATE TRIGGER actualizar AFTER INSERT ON productoscompra FOR EACH ROW 
        begin
        UPDATE saldoseccion 
        SET fechaActualizacion = NOW(), totalCompra = sum(NEW.productos.Precio *NEW.productoscompra.cantidad) /*Quiero el total de las compras realizadas*/
        WHERE IdSeccion in 
        (
        SELECT distinct
        secciones.IdSeccion
        FROM productos inner join productoscompra on Codigo=productos_Codigo inner join categorias on productos.IdCategoria = categorias.IdCategoria inner join secciones on secciones.IdSeccion = categorias.IdSeccion
        );
         
        end;
        $
        delimiter ;
```

Comment: La consulta que hay debajo funciona perfectamente por separado

Comment: J.A coloca por favor el mensaje de error completo tal cual lo obtienes

Comment: Ya lo he añadido